# React-admin Edit title missing record with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-admin

In order to use Typescript feature under react-admin, I followed [this official example](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/v3.11.0/examples/demo/src/orders/OrderEdit.tsx) to type the Edit title:

```js
interface UserTitleProps {
  record: UserRecord;
}
const UserTitle: FC<UserTitleProps> = ({ record }) => {
  const identifier = record?.email || record?.phoneNumber;

  if (record?.name) {
    return `${record?.name} (${identifier})`;
  }

  return identifier;
};
export const UserEdit: FC<EditProps> = (props) => (
  <Edit
    title={<UserTitle />}
    {...props}
  >
    <UserForm />
  </Edit>
);
```

But the code above gave me the following typescript error:

```
Property 'record' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'UserTitleProps'.  TS2741

    103 | export const UserEdit: FC<EditProps> = (props) => (
    104 |   <Edit
  > 105 |     title={<UserTitle />}
        |             ^
    106 |     {...props}
    107 |   >
    108 |     <UserForm />
```

Indeed, the `record` props is not really passed but according to the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html) and the following sample, there is nothing to add.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scrutinized this critically:

```js
interface UserTitleProps {
  record?: UserRecord; // make this an optional property
}
```

You'll notice that `record` is an optional property but in your code it's mandatory.
Therefore for your case, you'll need to pass the `record` prop.

But if you update that line, to make the prop optional, then `TypeScript` should stop complaining unless otherwise.

---

From their [page-title documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.5/CreateEdit.html#page-title)

> React-admin says that when you pass an element as `title`, it's cloned.
>  And from within `<EditView>`, the current record is injected to the `title`.

Therefore, you never have to pass the `record` prop explicitly.
And thus `record` should always be an "optional" prop when added to the interface since you never have to pass it directly.

[In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4Bh3k-YODY&feature=youtu.be), you can see what's happening underneath in case you're interested in the details.

```js
export const UserEdit: FC<EditProps> = (props) => {

  return (
    <Edit
      title={<UserTitle />} // "record" prop is never passed explicitly
      {...props}
    >
      <UserForm />
    </Edit>
  );
};
```

Comment: This indeed stop making Typescript complaining. However, that is the second issue: From where should I pass the record data to my component prop?

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you how to pass the `record` prop.

Comment: Thanks, I will try! But console.log looks very hacky here.

Comment: I tried, but this give me this TS error: `Property 'record' does not exist on type 'EditProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.`

Comment: So yes, TS is right because `record` is not part of the `EditProps` interface. I have updated the answer and added a [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4Bh3k-YODY&feature=youtu.be) in case you're interested in the details.

Comment: You're welcome. I see we're definitely in agreement of what's happening in the `<Edit>`'s `title` prop.

Answer (score 0):

This code helped me to deal with this issue. My code example that works:

```
const EditTitle = ( record : any ) => {
  return <span>Change feed state of {record.record ? `${record.record.feed}` : ''}</span>;
};
```

After I did debug printing, I realised that record is actually an object and contains record property with fields that I need. I use TS as well.